# Remove the parent array key in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array structure like this :

```
Array (

    [donate] => Array

    (
        [amount_other] => 222

        [pay_method] => Array
            (
                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [first_name] => sam
                        [last_name] => indi
                        [cc_type] => mc
                        [cc_number] => 5123456789012346
                        [cc_ccv2] => 111
                        [cc_exp_month] => 10
                        [cc_exp_year] => 20
                    )

            )

        [notes] => Test comment.
    )
```

)

I want to remove key [5] from the array, so that the new array becomes :

```
Array
```

(

```
[donate] => Array

    (
        [amount_other] => 222
        [pay_method] => Array

            (
                 [first_name] => sam
                 [last_name] => indi
                 [cc_type] => mc
                 [cc_number] => 5123456789012346
                 [cc_ccv2] => 111
                 [cc_exp_month] => 10
                 [cc_exp_year] => 20
            )

        [notes] => Test comment.
    )
```

)

I want this because the array key changes and I want to access the inner array directly so that I don't have to change the key each time in the code. If there are other ways to achieve this.. Please help.
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array['donate']['pay_method'] = current($array['donate']['pay_method']);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$array['donate']['pay_method'] = array_shift($array['donate']['pay_method']);
```